# Hypothesis testing on ratio of poisson means/rates with four parameters

Tags: hypothesis-testing, model-selection, poisson-distribution

I have two sets of count data, one with the application of drug and another without applying the drug. Let's assume the data at condition $1$ are $X_i^1$ and $X_j^1$. Similarly for condition $2$, the data is $X_i^2$ and $X_j^2$. Moreover we assume that the individual count data comes from a poisson distribution. So $X_i^1 \sim \lambda_i^1$, $X_j^1 \sim \lambda_j^1$, $X_i^2 \sim \lambda_i^2$, $X_j^2 \sim \lambda_j^2$. Now I frame my hypothesis as follows, 
\begin{align}
H_0 : \frac{\lambda_i^1}{\lambda_j^1} &= \frac{\lambda_i^2}{\lambda_j^2} 
&
H_1 : \frac{\lambda_i^1}{\lambda_j^1} & \neq \frac{\lambda_i^2}{\lambda_j^2}
\end{align}

So the intuition is if the ratio of rates does not change across conditions then we accept the null hypothesis, otherwise we reject it. I am searching for a mathematical analysis on this framework, that is, what should be the estimates for $\lambda$ in this situation. Please let me know if there is any paper that explained it.

Comment: You see there are two data points and I have four data points. Please look carefully before marking as duplicate. I would request you to reconsider.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think this has been asked before. I don't suppose it'll take too long to get a proper answer, but note that you can represent the data as counts in a contingency table & that your hypotheses concern the odds ratio.

Comment: Is the sample size random?  If not, then you don't actually have four independent parameters, in which case this question sounds like it might be equivalent to the standard textbook problem of testing independence in a $2\times 2$ contingency table.

Comment: I am sorry I don't exactly understand your question. I am not a statistician so may be I fail to understand what it you meant. I can give you a background that might reveal something. I am taking the gene expression counts from an experiment, that is how many reads come from a gene. Now there are reads that align to two genes. So I draw an edge between the genes, where genes are nodes of my graph. Now I want to delete some of the edges depending on their relative change across condition.

I don't understand though why sample size is related to independence.